# ListView builder expanding vertically when it is supposed to expand horizontally only [flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

This is a part of my application where the list view is expanding vertically as well. Originally I set the direction of the list view to axis horizontal but it is expanding on the vertical as well. I tried to set the size of the column to min but no luck.

[image]

As you can see there is a lot of gap before and after the listview. I don't really understand why it is there. What I want to do is to have no gaps before and after. How can I achieve this?

**This is the code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// widgets
import '../widgets/widgets.dart';

class ShopPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShopPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // route name
  static const String routeName = '/shop';

  // colors list
  final List<Color> colors = const [
    Color(0xFFEF9A9A),
    Color(0xFFF48FB1),
    Color(0xFFCE93D8),
    Color(0xFFB39DDB),
    Color(0xFF9FA8DA),
    Color(0xFF90CAF9),
    Color(0xFF81D4FA),
    Color(0xFF80DEEA),
    Color(0xFF80CBC4),
    Color(0xFFC5E1A5),
    Color(0xFFE6EE9C),
    Color(0xFFFFF59D),
    Color(0xFFFFE082),
    Color(0xFFFFCC80),
    Color(0xFFFFAB91),
    Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          size: 20,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.change_history,
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              size: 20,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            const Text(
              '20 rects',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 38.0),
            child: Text(
              'Companion colors',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 23),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 32,
                      width: 32,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: colors[index],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              itemCount: colors.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
            child: Button(
              text: 'SELECTED',
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap with `SizedBox` and provide item height.

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 32,
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 23),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Row(
```

With `SingleChildScrollView`

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Row(
      children: colors
          .map(
            (e) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
              child: Container(
                height: 32,
                width: 32,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: e,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Yeah! Thanks, it worked. But is it necessary to provide a fixed height? can't it adjust its height automatically according to the child content?

Comment: well you can use SingleChildScrollView for small cases like this. Also while we know the height, it would be better to provide fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

First let me tell your am not an expert but you can wrap your list view inside sized box and than give your column mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

```
Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 38.0),
              child: Text(
                'Companion colors',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Inter',
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 23),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 32,
                        width: 32,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: colors[index],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                itemCount: colors.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
              child: Button(
                text: 'SELECTED',
                color: Colors.white,
              ),),
            )
```